Overlaying a certain column with a blur div to hide the data underneath in Tabulator
I'm looking for advice on creating a blur overlay div to cover a specific column in a table. I want the overlay to show the header while hiding the cells in that column. It’s important that the overlay moves along with resizable columns and persists across pagination changes. How can I ensure the overlay remains in place and resizes properly with the columns? I want to write a text over the blur (so i need an overlayed div element). Think of it like a cover that hides the column underneath. Thank you for your help! I managed to put the overlay div on top of the columns and used
table.on("columnResized", positionOverlay);

yet, with this event, the resize is updated after the mouse movement has  ended. It does not simultaneously move with the columns.
And here is my positionOverlay function. Thank you for your help.
    function positionOverlay() {
        const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
        const tableElement = document.querySelector(".tabulator-tableholder");
        const column = table.getColumn("someColumn");
        const cellElement = column.getCells()[0]?.getElement();
  
            const rect = cellElement.getBoundingClientRect();
            const tableRect = tableElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            overlay.style.width = rect.width + "px";
            overlay.style.height = tableRect.height + "px";
            overlay.style.left = rect.left + "px";
            overlay.style.top = 34 + "px"; 
            overlay.style.display = "flex";
    }


What kind of blur, exactly? Might make more sense to use a pseudo element inside the relevant cells, positioned over the content. Then you would not need any resize handler to begin with.

Yes you are right, maybe I should have been more clear. I want to write a text over the blur (so i need an overlayed div element). Think of it like a cover that hides the column underneath.

According to the docs, there's also a columnResizing event. Compared with the columnResized event, the documentation tells you that it is executed when the user starts to resize a column, whereas columnResized (as the name suggests) runs after the column is resized. Have you tried that?

Another (generally possible, not knowing your specific requirements) solution would be to remove the column's data from the inital dataset before rendering the table - what's not rendered does not need to be hidden/obscured by a blur-effect.

Yes, weirdly columnResizing doesn't work :/ when we resize and leave the mouse and click to resize handler one more time, it finally resizes...

You might don't need JavaScript, checkout the new CSS function anchor():
But be aware of its coverage, it could be a valid option in the future, using it on production is NOT advised at this moment.


body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.table {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: white;
  border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  resize: both;
  anchor-name: --anchor-table;
  
  th, td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 4px 10px;
  }
}

.blur-column {
  anchor-name: --anchor-blur-column;
}

.blur {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: anchor(--anchor-blur-column bottom);
  left: anchor(--anchor-blur-column left);
  right: anchor(--anchor-blur-column right);
  bottom: anchor(--anchor-table bottom);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
}
<div class="blur"></div>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th class="blur-column">API Key</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Alice</td>
      <td>alice@example.com</td>
      <td>9A10F92C11E4B</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>bob@example.com</td>
      <td>8B29C93D13E5A</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Charlie</td>
      <td>charlie@example.com</td>
      <td>7C38D04E14F6C</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>David</td>
      <td>david@example.com</td>
      <td>6D47E15F15G7B</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>eve@example.com</td>
      <td>5E56F26G16H8A</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Frank</td>
      <td>frank@example.com</td>
      <td>4F67G37H17I9C</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Grace</td>
      <td>grace@example.com</td>
      <td>3G78H48I18J1B</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Hank</td>
      <td>hank@example.com</td>
      <td>2H89I59J19K2A</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Ivy</td>
      <td>ivy@example.com</td>
      <td>1I90J60K20L3C</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>Jack</td>
      <td>jack@example.com</td>
      <td>0J01K71L21M4B</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">View</a>
        <a href="#">Edit</a>
        <a href="#">Resize ↘</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>




This solution is the exact functionality I needed but yeah the compatibility issue makes it hard to use in production... Thanks though its a great solution

One approach could be to use the column formatter to apply a blur effect to each cell using filter css property. This won't work with IE but otherwise widely implemented. Couple ways to this:

Add an overlay div, as you suggested, to each cell element (Gender column below)
Directly add the blur to cell element (Color column below)

Please note this is a visual effect only.  Users can still get the blurred data if they really wanted, using Dev Tools for example.


const data = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12', gender: 'male', height: 1, col: 'red', dob: '', cheese: 1 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Mary May', age: '1', gender: 'female', height: 2, col: 'blue', dob: '14/05/1982', cheese: true },
  { id: 10, name: 'Margret Marmajuke', age: '16', gender: 'female', height: 5, col: 'yellow', dob: '31/01/1999' }
]

const table = new Tabulator('#table', {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
    { title: 'Age', field: 'age' },
    { title: 'Gender',
      field: 'gender',
      formatter: (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) => {
        onRendered(() => {
          const overlay = document.createElement('div')
          overlay.classList.add('overlay')
          
          cell.getElement().appendChild(overlay)
        });
        
        return cell.getValue()
      }
    },
    { title: 'Height', field: 'height' },
    { 
      title: 'Color',
      field: 'col',
      formatter: (cell, formatterParams, onRendered) => {
        cell.getElement().style.filter = 'blur(4px)'
        
        return cell.getValue()
      }
    }
  ]
})
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  z-index: 1000;
  user-select: none;
}
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.3.0/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@6.3.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>

<div id="table"></div>



